# How to navigate back to particular Page - Windows Phone 8

Tags: button, hardware, back

I could not find exactly what i need in the site, so my problem is the following:
If i navigate through pages like this: A -> B -> C (doing SQLite database update for selected vehicle from Page B) -> B (delete updated vehicle). And now when i press the hardware back button 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred. So I want the hardware button to navigate me back to the first page before 'B' ever. For example: A -> B -> C -> B (navigate back clicled) -> A or D -> B -> C -> B (navigate back clicled) -> D etc. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:
I created public static int 'pageIndex' on Page B (VehiclesPage.xaml) and I have access to Page B from another 4 pages so I am changing the index before navigate to B from each page. For example:

```
            From A->B
            VehiclesPage.pageIndex = 1;
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/VehiclesPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            From D->B
            VehiclesPage.pageIndex = 2;
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/VehiclesPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            etc...
```

And the method on VahiclesPage.xaml.cs:

```
        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

        switch (pageIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/RefuelingPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case 2:
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/OtherCostsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case 3:
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/StatisticsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case 4:
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/CalculatorPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
        }
    }
```